# CSV File to list

Tags: python, list, text, csv

I have a CSV file which is made of words in the first column. (1 word per row)

I need to print a list of these words, i.e.

CSV File:

```
a
and
because
have
```

Output wanted:

```
"a","and","because","have"
```

I am using python and so far I have the follwing code;

```
text=open('/Users/jessieinchauspe/Dropbox/Smesh/TMT/zipf.csv')
text1 = ''.join(ch for ch in text)
for word in text1:
    print  '"' + word + '"' +','
```

This is returning:

```
"a",
"",
"a",
"n",
...
```

Whereas I need everything one one line, and not by character but by word.
Thank you for your help!

EDIT: this is a screenshot of the preview of the CSV file
[image: preview of the CSV file]

Comment: Does the file always only have a single word per line? Or may it have multiple comma-separated fields?

Comment: have you looked into the csv library python provides?

Comment: @BenButler-Cole yes it's always one single word per line.

Comment: The line `''.join(ch for ch in text)` is equivalent to `''.join(text)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop over the file directly:

```
with open('/Users/jessieinchauspe/Dropbox/Smesh/TMT/zipf.csv') as text:
    print ','.join('"{0}"'.format(word.strip()) for word in text)
```

The above code:

- Loops over the file; this gives you a line (including the newline `\n` character).
- Uses `.strip()` to remove whitespace around the word (including the newline).
- Uses `.format()` to put the word in quotes (`'word'` becomes `'"word"'`)
- Uses `','.join()` to join all quoted words together into one list with commas in between.

Comment: I support this answer.  :), although technically speaking, `.strip()` can remove a whole lot more than just the newline.  That might be desired, but if not, OP could use `word.rstrip('\n')` or simple slicing:  `word[:-1]`.

Comment: This is equivalent to and a bit nicer than my solution.

Comment: @mgilson: I've clarified a little, my explanation was indeed not complete.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, returns a long string of all the words next to each other : "aandhaveableaccordinlgy .... "

Comment: @Julia: Your input example gives me `"a","and","because","have"`; to get your output, `text` would have to be one long word already instead of a file with one word per line.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the file.. It seems very strange that no answer is working..

Comment: Yes, exactly. It must be a problem on my end.... I've found a way to solve my problem, see omu_negru answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you do :
    text=open('/Users/jessieinchauspe/Dropbox/Smesh/TMT/zipf.csv')
that basically returns an iterator with each line as an element. If you want a list out of that and you're sure that there is only one word per line than all you need to do is

```
  result=list(text)
  print result
```

Otherwise you can get the first words only like so :

```
 result = list(x.split(',')[0] for x in text)
 print result
```

Comment: this returns ["a\rand\rbecause\rhave\r ... \rzero"]

Comment: I used this and then copied into Word and replaces \r by ","... not a nice way to do it at all but it worked..

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the CSV module:

```
import csv

input_f = '/Users/jessieinchauspe/Dropbox/Smesh/TMT/zipf.csv'
output_f = '/Users/jessieinchauspe/Dropbox/Smesh/TMT/output.csv'

with open(input_f, 'r') as input_handle, open(output_f, 'w') as output_handle:
    writer = csv.writer(output_handle)
    writer.writerow(list(input_handle))
```

Comment: I wonder why `writerow` requires a sequence object instead of any generic iterable ...

Comment: @mgilson: Now that I think about it, it is odd. I'll have to see if that's right.

Comment: It is right.  The docs say `sequence` and if you try to write a row with a generator expression, an Exception is raised.  I tried `inspect.getsourcelines` on it, but that failed miserably -- presumably because it is a C implementation.

Comment: I get the following : Traceback (most recent call last):
    writer.writerow(list(input_handle))
IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: @Julia: Whoops, that last `'r'` should've been a `'w'`.

Comment: quite strange, the only thing it does is deletes the contents of the zipf.csv file... no output file is created

Comment: @Julia: Sorry, more mistakes. The second `output_f` should've been `input_f`.

Comment: no worries :) now the output file consists of all the words in the first cell. Don't understand why none of the answers are working :/

Answer (score 0):

If you put a comma at the end of the print statement it suppresses the newline.

```
print  '"' + word + '"' +',',
```

Will give you the output on one line.

Comment: OP will need to get rid of `text1 = ''.join(ch for ch in text)` as well.

Comment: This solution gives an extra comma at the end of the line.

Comment: this is exactly what i would need but it considers each character to be a separate word : ", "t", "l", "y", "
", "c", "o", "n", "s", "i", "d", "e", "r", "
"

Answer (score 0):

`print ','.join('"%s"' % line.strip() for line in open('/tmp/test'))`

Comment: doesn't seem to work, returns a long string of all the words together: "aandbecausehaveaccordingly ...."